# pytumblr's client.reblog allowed fields exception

Tags: python, tumblr

I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something here, hopefully it can be pointed out to me.

When attempting to reblog a post with a caption and tags I'm receiving back

> caption,tags are not allowed fields

When client.reblog checks against _post_valid_options I see that it should at the very least be receiving back tags as valid.

[reblog function](https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr/blob/6fd1c97e375f4273e9b786dba8f1ff1494d62d9a/pytumblr/__init__.py#L407)

[_post_valid_options function](https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr/blob/6fd1c97e375f4273e9b786dba8f1ff1494d62d9a/pytumblr/__init__.py#L465)

I also noticed that it's checking for a type in kwargs, attempting to add a type as well returns back the same exception including type being not allowed this time.

> caption,type,tags are not allowed fields

My code

```
    data = {'blogname': 'form.cleaned_data['blogname'],
            'id': form.cleaned_data['id'],
            'reblog_key': form.cleaned_data['reblog_key'],
            'type': 'photo',
            'comment': form.cleaned_data['caption'],
            'tags': tags}

    response = client.reblog(**data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently this is due to installing the pytumblr package through pip.  The pytumblr package in pypy is outdated compared to what's currently in git.  Removing the pypy version (pytumblr 0.0.5) and installing directly from git (pip install git+https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr.git).

If you're running into this issue make sure you're using the version direct from the git repo and not the pypy version, if it hasn't been updated yet that is.

I opened an issue with the devs on Github to see if they can update the pypy version or update the readme to let folks know to use the git repo.

https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr/issues/47